# Tricky algebra question: Solving $R = \frac{a(SR)^d}{b^d + (SR)^d}$ for $R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following equation for $R$:

$$R = \frac{a(SR)^d}{b^d + (SR)^d}$$

So far I can only find a solution when $d=1$.

Would appreciate any input or help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: In general, this is equivalent to solving the trinomial $x^d + x + c = 0$, which does not admit a general solution in radicals.  You can get solutions for $d=2$ and $d=-1$ by quadratic equation, but things will get complicated as $d$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

For rational $d$,

$$b^d-aS^dR^{d-1}+S^dR^d=0$$

is a polynomial equation or can be made so (by $R^{p/q}=(\sqrt[q]R)^p$).

Such equations are known to have no general closed-form solution, except for a few exponents.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$Rb^d+S^dR^{d+1}=aS^dR^d$$ and then you will need a numerical method.
Remark: $d=2$ and $d=3$ are solvable by radicals.
For $d=2$ is one solution:
$$R={\frac {1/2\,aS+1/2\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}{S}^{2}-4\,{b}^{2}}}{S}}$$